# How do I change the up action icon into button with text on Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to change the style of the Up action button. It currently looks like this:

[image]

After much exploration on stack overflow and the Android documentation, I have seen examples where the Up action button icon can be swapped for a custom icon, like so:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

This, however, is not what I'm looking for. I would like to replace the Up action button's icon with text, such as the button on the right side of the above screenshot.

Is there a way (from the java side) for me to replace this arrow icon with text that says "Cancel" without modifying or creating any drawable resources or layout files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that without a custom action bar layout in Android. In order to set a custom action bar, you need to do the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:text="Contact"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And set the layout in your action bar from your activity like the following.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar_layout, null);
    TextView cancelButton = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll give this a try and let you know.

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know if there's a problem. :)

Comment: This actually worked out pretty well for me. Thanks again for the prompt response!

Comment: Great to know that I could help. You are welcome.. :)